# Custom function is not recognized

Tags: function, powershell, module

A function that I dotted-in to my PowerShell profile is not available during my current session. The function looks like this:

```
# \MyModules\Foobar.ps1

function Foo-Bar {
    Write-Host "Foobar";
}

# Test loading of this file
Foo-Bar;
```

And my profile looks like this:

```
# \Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

Write-Host "Loading MyModules..."
Push-Location ~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\MyModules

.\Foobar.ps1

Pop-Location
Write-Host "Done"
```

When I run `. $profile` the output looks as follows, which confirms the `Foo-Bar` function works.

```
> . $profile 

Loading MyModules...
Foobar
Done
```

Running the `Foo-Bar` function after that, though, explodes like this:

```
Foo-Bar : The term 'Foo-Bar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:1 char:1
+ Foo-Bar
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Foo-Bar:String) [],        
                              CommandNotFoundException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Why isn't it available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of ways to approach it. Note, neither one of these approaches will require you to dot-invoke your module before importing it.

1) use a proper module `MyMethod.psm1`

```posh
# MyMethod.psm1 (m for module)
function MyMethod {
    # my method
}
Export-ModuleMember MyMethod

# then in your profile
Import-Module "MyMethod"
```

2) if you have a collection of methods and need to break them into multiple files

```posh
# MyMethod1.ps1
function Invoke-MyMethod1{
    # my method1
}
Set-Alias imm Invoke-MyMethod1
```

```posh
# MyMethod2.ps1
function Something-MyMethod2 {
    # my method2
}
Set-Alias smm Something-MyMethod2
```

```posh
# MyMethod.psm1 (m for module)
Push-Location $psScriptRoot
. .\MyMethod1.ps1
. .\MyMethod2.ps1
Pop-Location

Export-ModuleMember `
    -Alias @(
        '*') `
    -Function @(
          'Invoke-MyMethod1',
          'Something-MyMethod2')
```

```posh
# then in your profile
Import-Module "MyMethod"
```

Comment: Does MyMethod.psm1 need to live within the Modules directory?

Comment: Yep, that's a great spot for it :)

Comment: @ShaunLuttin you could also create a folder within the modules directory with the same name as your `psm1` file. This will allow good separation and not bloat your modules directory.